# Active Directory permissions dissapears

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, user-permissions

I have recently configured Active directory delegation and in one specific OU inherited permissions disappears from all users except one I have recently created for tests.
Non of the users are a member of protected groups like:
Enterprise Admins, Schema Admins, Domain Admins, Backup Operators etc.

It doesn't matter if the permissions are inherited or even if I directly applied them to the object.
I've e tried to move users outside the OU and move it back but the problem remains.

Comment: Turn on [Diagnostic Logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961809.aspx) for "Internal Processing"

Answer (score 1):

I've ran a very small tool ADFind to list all protected groups in our environment and the problem was actually protected groups. All those members except the new one, were member of a security group which was transitive member of Print Operators.